# Como mostrar diferentes paginas con el router

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy realizando una practica con el router de Vue 3, pero me estoy encontrando con un problema y es que al momento de querer mostrar las diferentes vistas no lo puedo hacer pues genera problemas con mis componentes, y es que según tengo entendido para poder mostrar las vista necesito router-view pero si hago esto la vista se genera abajo de mis componentes, intente una manera de validar con un if y así ver que muestro si mis componentes o mi vista pero me parece una forma no optima para hacerlo. 
Este es mi codigo en Vue:

```
<template>
  <h2>Proyectos</h2>

  <div class="actions">
    <router-link to="/proyectos/crear" class="action__add">
      <i class="material-icons-outlined">
        add
      </i>
      Crear Proyecto
    </router-link>
    <input type="text" class="action__search" placeholder="Buscar..." />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-content">
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
    <list-project />
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
import ListProject from '../../components/project/ListProject.vue';
export default {
  components: { ListProject },
};
</script>
```

Este es mi router:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/proyectos',
    name: 'Project',
    component: () => import('../views/project/AppContent.vue'),
    children : [
      {
        path: 'crear',
        component: () => import('../views/project/AppCreate.vue')
      }
    ]
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Genero muchas veces list-project pues estoy realizando una practica.

Comment: a ver, no entiendo lo siguiente: Vos estas hablando de intercambiar entre vistas, pero realmente solo tenes un link a la vista ``/proyectos/crear``. Ahora bien, abajo de este link, tenes ese codigo repetido con muchos componentes ``list-proyect``. Luego de todo esto tenes el router-view. Quiere decir que ahi (donde está router-view) es donde el contenido de la aplicacion va a cambiar cuando toques un link. Lo ideal seria que vos tengas una carpeta de vistas, con sus componentes conectados en el router. Un header donde tengas todos los links a las distintas vistas. (sigo en otro comentario)

Comment: Luego en app.vue llamas a ese header, y abajo le agregas <router-view>. De esa manera tu app va a tener un encabezado estático, y va a cambiar el contenido de abajo.